# How to fix " Unhandled rebase type 1 " Git error

Tags: git

I am getting `BUG: builtin/rebase.c:1161: Unhandled rebase type 1` when I am executing `git rebase --continue` command. When I searched the web, it looks like a known bug, https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3537. The bug is closed and the Git version I am using is latest version.

Please advise.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Git Version
[image]

Comment: Can you provide any information on how to reproduce it?

Comment: What previous command you executed? How your git tree looks like?

Comment: @funnydman I executed git rebase, had some conflicts so executed git megetool and fixed conflicts and then added files, then I executed git rebase continue command, when I got the error.

Comment: Which git version are you using? Execute `git version` and show us the output.

Comment: It might be that the type of rebase you executed got lost, corrupt rebase file perhaps?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen added version screenshot in answer.

Comment: @Justinas updated answer with git tree.

Comment: How did you start the rebase? Can you show the original start command? It seems the problem here is that internally the code is trying to use an old rebase type that is now handled by the interactive one, so it should probably not use that type any more. So this seems like a bug to me, yes.

Comment: A type-1 rebase is `git rebase --merge`, which apparently isn't supposed to get to this case. If you find a reproducer and send it to the Git mailing list, the Git folks will fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't supposed to be able to trigger `BUG` output from Git: seeing that output means that there's a bug.  We assumed that case would never happen, and it looks like we were wrong.  Oops.

As torek mentioned, you should try to reproduce this with a test case and send it to the mailing list as outlined [on the website](https://git-scm.com/community).  We will happily address the issue if you do.

Even if you're not exactly sure how to reproduce it, if you have the list of commands that you ran from starting the rebase, it may still be worth reporting, since we may be able to intuit what went wrong without a full test case.

Comment: This bug happened to me while using Git kraken. I had a commit A and later I had commit B, which was reverting changes done in commit A. During interactive rebase I moved those two commits to be the last actions in interactive rebase and selected that B should squash to A (I thought this will result in disappearance of those two commits). Instead I got this bug.

Comment: I also had it today when using GitKraken when doing an interactive rebase. I did 4 squashes and 1 reword.

Comment: Please send an email to the Git list.  Telling us here is not likely to result in any useful changes, but there is probably someone familiar with this code (not me) who would be happy to help fix it.

Comment: Just encountered this bug. Looks like it confused two files, one delete, and one added. The deleted file was gone, but the 'delete' didn't register as a change. The deletion showed up in a later commit, but was transient. If I popped the commit that contained the deletion, the deletion didnt' show up. When I integrated the deletion into the earlier commit, correcting it, I then tried to rebase the commit that had the extra deletion. It then though a file I added wasn't real. I had to delete this unrelated file to complete the rebase and avoid this bug. Then re-add the unrelated file manually.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same "Type 1"error on Eclipse git GUI. Then, when I chose "skip commit", the seemingly strange error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this today.  It was caused in a very complex way.  I was using GitKraken and when it complained about an ongoing rebase, I then attempted it by hand with git rebase --continue.
And I saw what it noted above.  I will see if I can determine....

Attempting to rebase quit, complains about a .git/rebase-merge directory.
.....
So I deleted the rebase-merge directory and went on..
I suspect that one can determine (in the future) what edge case was not normal, but considering what happens when a rebase is halted in the middle or not completed...
So whatever the edge case was that caused this failure, is actually a case that can happen...

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem using a nodejs file watcher with Ubuntu via WSL 1 (Window Subsystem for Linux). The `.git/rebase-merge` directory was impossible to delete from Window or Ubuntu but deleted itself automatically when stopping the nodejs process.

It seems like the directory was in some "to delete" task list of the system but wasn't actually deleted until released from the watcher.
This would probably not happen on a non-hybrid Ubuntu or Windows machine